# Can't get widgets to appear in front page in customization, WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I wan't to add a instagram feed to my page in wordpress, and for that I need a widget. But I can't get my widgets to appear in the customization of my page. And I've tried to make the page static and add the widget from appearence/widget.
How can I add the widget? Is there a way to integrate instagram without widget. I need it at the bottom of my page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried dynamic_sidebar('widget name here') ?

Answer (score 1):

instagram feed plugin must give you code like [instagram feed241]

when you get this code you should add this code to your first page and for doing this 
you can add html code in custumizer
or you can page builders like elementor